# Redirect webpage on key event

Tags: javascript

What I want to do is, configure a keyboard key, and then, when I click it, will redirect to another webpage.
Can someone tell me what is wrong with my code or if there's another way to do this?

```
function redirectpagina () {
    window.location="Pagina KITT Parque.html"
}
window.addEventListener("keyup", function(e){ if(e.keyCode == 8) redirectpagina (); },  false);
```

Answer (score 0):

`keyCode` only works with printable keys. For the others (including `backspace`), you have to use `which`.

```
window.addEventListener("keyup", function(e){ if(e.which == 8) redirectpagina (); },  false);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a complete working page (at least on my browser).

```
<html>
<body>
<h3>type G for Google</h3>
<script>
function redirectpagina () {
window.location="http://www.google.com"
}

window.addEventListener(        
"keyup", 
function(e){ 
  if (e.keyCode > 13)
      window.alert(e.keyCode);
  if(e.keyCode == 71) 
      redirectpagina (); 
});
</script>
```